# How to send a single XMPP message with php

Tags: php, xmpp

I am using a free hosting service for my php and im using it to send a XMPP message to my Jabber account. However, XMPPHP seems to not work whenever im using it.

The reason I am using a hosted PHP script is because I don't have a private IP and my script needs to receive a POST request from webhook to then send a XMPP message back to my computer at home

I tried using converse.js but the lack of documentation on how to use it to send a single message prevented me from using it

```
    $conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('conversejs.org', 5222, 'iot_d34dc0de', 
    'myPassword', '', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);    
    try {
        $conn->connect();
        $conn->processUntil('session_start');
        $conn->presence();
        $conn->message('d34dc0de@xabber.org', 'This is a test message!');
        $conn->disconnect();
    } catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Im expecting to send a message to d34dc0de@xabber.org but im not even sure it can connect